# PHP usort inside foreach order alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I am trying to figure out why my code wont work as i expect. I have an array:

```
$persons = array(
    0 => array(
        'person' => 'John',
        'children' => array('Eve', 'Mark', 'Alto')
    ),
    1 => array(
        'person' => 'Susy',
        'children' => array('Ruby', 'Adam', 'Tõnu')
    )
);
```

Loop the array and sort childrens alphabetically

```
foreach( $persons as $person ) {

    usort($person['children'], function( $a, $b ) {
        return strcmp( $a, $b );
    });
    var_dump($person['children']); //shows children array items alphabetically ordered

}
```

But after foreach chidrens are still in starting order

```
var_dump($persons); //shows that children names are not ordered alphabetically
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` loop is creating what is effectively a copy of the array value inside the loop.  The copy is sorted but not altering the original array.  To do so you can make it a reference with `&`:

```
foreach ($persons as &$person) {
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> On each iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to $value and the internal array pointer is advanced by one... In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Another way to reference the arrays directly is to iterate over the indexes and reference the elements:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($persons); $i++) {
    usort($persons[$i]['children']), function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a, $b);
    });
}
```

Comment: You got an error on your syntax there is a `)` before the second argument